# PHP Custom CMS - How to handle settings

Tags: php, content-management-system, settings

I'm currently trying to find a way to handle settings on my custom CMS (just a playground to learn PHP). I have database table that stores all settings. My temporary solution is a function that returns one dimensional array with query results.

```
  // Get settings from db.
  function getPanelOptions( $pdo ) {
    $options = [];
    $getOptions = $pdo->query( 'SELECT option_name, option_value FROM bp_options' );

    while( $result = $getOptions->fetch() ) {
      $options[ $result['option_name'] ] = $result['option_value'];
    }

    return $options;
  }

  $bpOptions = getPanelOptions( $pdo ); // Get settings to arr.
  // Example use
  if( $bpOptions['post_max_lenght'] === 400 ) ...
```

I've read a lot that global variables are not best way to do this, so I call function in file that is included on every page. I don't have problem with using hard coded variable, because I won't change it (even so I can replace all occurrences in sublime). My biggest problem is that I can't find a way to use settings to create a 'wrapper' functions like in WordPress, for example 'getHtmlLang()'. In JS it would be easy, but in PHP I need to pass setting to this function, at it gets to lengthy.

```
// Now i use
<html lang="<?php echo $bpOptions['panel_lang']; ?>">

// I'd like some wrapper function.
<html <?php getHtmlLang() ?>>
```

I'm not familiar with OOP in PHP so maybe this is way to achieve this, or should I simply use global because it's justified?

Comment: Where do you declare `getHtmlLang()` ?

Comment: It's just an example, this function would return lang="" with setting value. But now to make it work I would need to pass param like getHtmlLand( $bpOptions['panel_lang'] ) and it gets lengthy.